# Filter an HtmlNodeCollection based on the InnerText of one of its child elements?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have an HtmlNodeCollection `var searchResults` that I scrape from a website. I use HtmlAgilityPack. Here's an example of 3 Nodes inside it (there are more ofc):

```
  <a href="/node/375516" class="search-item search-item--column"><div class="search-item__image">
    <img class="search-item__image-file" src="/themes/custom/rtlnieuws/images/placeholder-image.png" alt="Meer hofnarren gevraagd">
    </div><div class="search-item__content">
    <span class="search-item__label chapeau">Economie</span>
    <h2 class="search-item__title">Meer hofnarren gevraagd
    </h2>
    <p class="search-item__description"> Na afloop van een uitzending van @Z stonden we nog even na te praten. Het ging over koningsdrama’s en dolkstoten in de rug, naar aanleiding van de strijd om het leiderschap bij de PvdA. De vraag: is de strijd om de macht harder in de politiek dan in het b...
    </p>
    <span class="search-item__date">18 oktober 2016 om 06:03</span>
    </div></a>

  <a href="/node/1248576" class="search-item search-item--artikel"><div class="search-item__image">
    <img class="search-item__image-file" src="https://beta.rtlnieuws.nl/sites/default/files/styles/square_small/public/content/images/2015/02/19/ANP190215025-1.jpeg?itok=-IvKlGdN" alt="'Oud-vastgoeddirecteur Philips verdacht van fraude'">
    </div><div class="search-item__content">
    <span class="search-item__label chapeau">Geld en Werk</span>
    <h2 class="search-item__title">'Oud-vastgoeddirecteur Philips verdacht van fraude'
    </h2>
    <p class="search-item__description"> De voormalige directeur vastgoed van technologiebedrijf Philips in de VS staat binnenkort terecht in een fraudezaak. Beurstoezichthouder Securities and Exchange Commission (SEC) heeft hem aangeklaagd wegens het doorspelen van voorwetenschap over aankopen van Philips in 2006. 
    </p>
    <span class="search-item__date">8 april 2015 om 07:31</span>
    </div></a>

  <a href="/node/1320871" class="search-item search-item--artikel"><div class="search-item__image">
    <img class="search-item__image-file" src="https://beta.rtlnieuws.nl/sites/default/files/styles/square_small/public/content/images/archive/d0/jan-van-v-800.jpg?itok=tdDQaNSo" alt="Hof straft zwaarder in Klimop-fraudeproces">
    </div><div class="search-item__content">
    <span class="search-item__label chapeau">Geld en Werk</span>
    <h2 class="search-item__title">Hof straft zwaarder in Klimop-fraudeproces
    </h2>
    <p class="search-item__description"> Het Amsterdamse Gerechtshof heeft zeven van de 12 verdachten in het vastgoedfraudeproces zwaardere straffen gegeven dan de rechtbank. Jan van Vlijmen, de hoofdverdachte in de Klimopzaak, moet zeven jaar de cel in. 
    </p>
    <span class="search-item__date">27 februari 2015 om 13:49</span>
    </div></a>
```

I want to filter the Nodes and only keep the ones that have a certain keyword in the inner text of the `<h2 class="search-item__title">` element.

I'm trying this:

```
    string keyWord = "fraude";
    var filteredNodes = searchResults.Select(s => s.SelectNodes("//h2[contains( text(), " + keyWord + " )]/ancestor::a"));
```

But the problem is that the filteredNodes becomes `IEnumerable<HtmlNodeCollection>`, not `HtmlNodeCollection`. I need to have an HtmlNodeCollection for further logic in the code.

Is there a different way to filter the nodes based on the inner text of one of the elements? I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me. "doc" is  a HtmlDocument. To me it's not clear why you are using HtmlNodeCollection rather than HtmlDocument.

```
string keyWord = "fraude";
HtmlNodeCollection tr = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes($"//h2[contains(., '{keyWord}')]/ancestor::a");
```

If you really want to start from HtmlNodeCollection the following code applies. Only the last two elements are returned in the collection. I'm adding the OuterHtml of your searchResults in a string to create a new HtmlDocument:

```
 string res = null;
 for (int i = 0; i < tr.Count; i++)
 {
 res += searchResults[i].OuterHtml;
 }
 HtmlDocument doc2 = new HtmlDocument();
 doc2.LoadHtml(res);
 string newKeyword = "Klimop";
 HtmlNodeCollection tr2 = doc2.DocumentNode.SelectNodes($"//h2[contains(., '{newKeyword}')]/ancestor::a");
```